# Critical review of a Simple Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

```
public partial class CreateAdmin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        #region Events.

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadOrganizations();
            }
        }

        // Save Admin and Organization Admin in db.
        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Save user info in aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership
                MembershipUser user = SaveMemberShipUser();

                // If user is saved successfully.
                if (user != null)
                {
                    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        using (var context = new RideshareEntities())
                        {
                            Save(context, (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey);

                            // Commit transaction and save all changes in db.
                            transaction.Complete();
                            context.AcceptAllChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Equals("The username is already in use."))
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "The username(Email) is alrady in use.";
                    return;
                }

                // TODO: Remove throw and handle exception(Log error in file)
                throw;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Class Methods.

        // Load organizations in CheckboxList
        private void LoadOrganizations()
        {
            chklstOrganizations.DataTextField = "Name";
            chklstOrganizations.DataValueField = "OrganizationId";

            // More than 2 will break formatting if user add long organization name
            chklstOrganizations.RepeatColumns = 2;

            chklstOrganizations.DataSource = RidersService.GetOrganizations();
            chklstOrganizations.DataBind();
        }

        // Save user info in aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership
        private MembershipUser SaveMemberShipUser()
        {
            MembershipUser user = null;

            //Adds a new user.
            user = Membership.CreateUser(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtEmail.Text);
            user.IsApproved = true;
            user.Comment = Utility.RandomString(15);

            Membership.UpdateUser(user);

            return user;
        }

        // Save Admin and Organizations.
        private void Save(RideshareEntities context, Guid userId)
        {
            // Get admin object with data.
            Admin admin = GetNewAdminWithData();

            // Assign userId to admin.
            admin.UserId = userId;

            // Add in context and save.
            context.Admins.AddObject(admin);
            context.SaveChanges();

            // Save selected organizations.
            SaveOrganizations(context, admin.AdminId);
        }

        // Save Organizations.
        private void SaveOrganizations(RideshareEntities context, int adminId)
        {
            // Loop through each items in checked list bxo.
            foreach (ListItem item in chklstOrganizations.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    int organizationid = 0;

                    // If item successfully parsed in int then save data in OrganizationAdmin table.
                    if (int.TryParse(item.Value, out organizationid))
                    {
                        OrganizationAdmin organizationAdmin = new OrganizationAdmin();
                        organizationAdmin.AdminId = adminId;
                        organizationAdmin.OrganizationId = organizationid;

                        context.OrganizationAdmins.AddObject(organizationAdmin);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Get New Admin object with data populated..
        private Admin GetNewAdminWithData()
        {
            Admin admin = new Admin();

            admin.Email = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
            admin.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
            admin.LastName = txtLastName.Text.Trim();
            admin.ContactNo = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtContNumber.Text.Trim()) ? txtContNumber.Text.Trim() : null;
            admin.Address = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text.Trim()) ? txtAddress.Text.Trim() : null;
            admin.City = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCity.Text.Trim()) ? txtCity.Text.Trim() : null;
            admin.State = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtState.Text.Trim()) ? txtState.Text.Trim() : null;
            admin.Zip = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtZip.Text.Trim()) ? txtZip.Text.Trim() : null;

            return admin;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't like that you are using exceptions to determine if the email address is already in use.  Exceptions are for **exceptional behaviour**, not something that is to be (reasonably) expected.  It's not that unlikely that someone will try to use the same email address to register on a website (they may have forgotten that they had registered).  Checks like that should be done in a separate method, eg:

```
private bool IsValid()
{
    //check if username is valid by querying the database
    //display an error message if it is and return false.  
    //return true otherwise.
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsValid())
    {
        return
    }

    //perform your save logic.
}
```

The following method should have a lowercase S for the "ship" as that is how the class is named.

```
private MembershipUser SaveMemberShipUser()
```

This line has got [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) written all over it:

```
user = Membership.CreateUser(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtEmail.Text);
```

Never use user inputted text directly, use a prepared statement instead.